# Getting bad request with AndroidNetworking.upload()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-networking, fast-android-networking

`AndroidNetworking.upload()` is giving bad request in every case.
Testing API on postman which is working fine, but unable to create the same request in AndroidNetworking, any help would be appreciated

Tried `AndroidNetworking.post()` method which gives a proper response from the server (asking to send file) but in that request unable to add a multipart file, which is required from for server to process.

```
var request = Rx2AndroidNetworking.upload(ApiEndPoint.SUBMIT_KYC_DOCUMENT)
request.setContentType("multipart/form-data")


request.addMultipartParameter ("json","{\"POADocumentType\":40,   \"POIDocumentType\":60,\"ReSubmitDocument\":false}","text/plain")


    try {
        if (selfie.docFront != null) {
            request.addMultipartFile("Selfie", selfie.docFront,"multipart/form-data")
        }
    } catch (unInitialsied: UninitializedPropertyAccessException) {

    }

    return request.build()
        .setUploadProgressListener(object : UploadProgressListener {
            override fun onProgress(bytesUploaded: Long, totalBytes: Long) {
                Log.d("", "")
            }
        })
        .getAsJSONObject(object : JSONObjectRequestListener {
            override fun onResponse(response: JSONObject?) {
                Log.d("", "")
            }

            override fun onError(anError: ANError?) {
                Log.d("", "")
            }
        })
```

By the way, it's working in postman
https://ibb.co/3W4qKR6

Answer (score 2):

I dont know how this android networking library works in kotlin but my issue got resolved when I commented

```
AndroidNetworking.enableLogging();
```

All my multipart call in this library works fine,after commenting it.

Comment: you saved my day, they are doing silly mistakes and we are wasting out time...